# How can the given formula yield a frequency, when it doesn't have a parameter with time units?

Tags: electromagnetism, frequency

This is the formula for plasma frequency.

$$w_{plasma} = \sqrt{\frac{4 \pi n e^2}{m} }$$

How can this formula yield a frequency, when it doesn't have a parameter with time units?

Comment: Can you give more information on the equation? The definition of the variables?

Comment: It has other units that can be expressed in terms of time units - like charge.

Comment: Why is this considered homework-like or check-my-work? It's a perfectly reasonable question from someone apparently encountering Gaussian units for the first time.

Comment: I agree @JohnDoty , the people on this site can just get pretty territorial about their personal definitions for question tags.

Answer (score 4):

Your formula is in [Gaussian Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units#Unit_of_charge), where charge has the dimensions  g^(1/2) cm^(3/2) s^(−1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you happen to know what the value of e is in this context?

Comment: 4.80320427 × 10^−10 ESU

Answer (score -1):

The formula is in 'natural units'.  If it were in Gaussian units, it would have factors=of c and ${\hbar}$.  In natural units, $e^2/(2m_{\rm electron})=r_c=2.82\times 10^{-13}$ cm. Use $r_c/c=2.82\times 10^{-13}/3\times 10^{-8}$ to get time in sec.
Then, multiplying by $n=(N/cm^3)\times c^3$ would give frequency in $1/sec.$$

Comment: Huh? Classical phenomenon, no ℏ involved. c isn't needed in this case, either: http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~shuleli/papers/fund.pdf

Comment: In SI units $\omega= \sqrt{n_e e^2/m \epsilon_0}$.

Comment: In  natural units, $e^2$ is dimensionless and equals 1/137, the fine structure constant.  In Gaussian units, this becomes $e^2/({\hbar}c)=1/137$.  By using $e^2/(2m)=r_c$, the $\hbar$ was not needed in this formula.  Even in SI units, $\hbar$ is introduced to make the EM coupling constant dimensionless.            $\epsilon_0$ in SI units is $4\pi c^2$, adjusted by powers of ten.

Comment: [Plasma oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation) - this is where the formula comes from (there are expressions in SI and Gaussian units).

Comment: What Wikipedia calls "cgs units" is really natural units.  "cgs units" could mean Gaussian, esu, or emu.  It is not Gaussian in the wiki because there is no $c^2$.  I was responding to the formula asked about, and this seems to have led to some confusion.